# how to generate permanent s3 object/file url (without expiration)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want generate S3 object URL with no expiration.

My S3 bucket and objects are private as i don't want it to set public.

I tried generating pr_signed url using lambda function but it only validates for 7 days.

Help if anybody knows.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is a contradiction in what you are saying, because an object with a URL that does not expire is -- for all practical purposes -- the same thing as a publicly-accessible object.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it has max 604800 seconds(7 days) max to exipre..

But

If You have to make public read for ACL and it will be given non expiring url...

```
obj = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']).object(object_name)
obj.write(:file => image_location)
obj.acl = :public_read
obj.public_url.to_s
```

Or you can use scheduler  in cloud watch  that will run on or before 604800 secs and renew the expiration...

Write a lambda with this

```
url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='get_object',
    Params={
        'Bucket': 'bucket-name',
        'Key': 'key-name'
    },
    ExpiresIn=604800
)
```

and run it in cloud watch  scheduler on or before 7 days(10080)

```
aws events put-rule --schedule-expression "rate(10079 minute)" --name bef7day
```